# Selecting a div matching an attribute using JQuery is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, click, simulate

I go to https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=BINANCE:BTCUSDTPERP and press OPT+g (ALT+g for non-mac) and a TimeRange overlay appears.

[image]

I'm trying to simulate clicking on the 'Custom range' tab using JavaScript from the console.

But `$('#overlap-manager-root > div > [attribute="CustomRange"]')` fails to retrieve it.

This is odd to me because `$('#overlap-manager-root > div button')` successfully picks out the 2 buttons.

I'm using https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ for reference.

Comment: When you do $('#overlap-manager-root > div [data-value="CustomRange"]').click(); it works

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thankyou! If you would care to put this as an answer I will close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`>` combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators) is for direct descendants. This means the element after the `>` needs to be in the parent element (the element named before `>`) directly and not in some child element.

For example, `#overlap-manager-root > div > [data-value="CustomRange"]` would match

```
<div id="overlap-manager-root">
   <div>
       <button data-value="CustomRange"></button>
   </div>
</div>
```

But would not match

```
<div id="overlap-manager-root">
   <div>
       <div id="someotherdiv">
          <button data-value="CustomRange"></button>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Removing the `>` will make it look for any element within the subhierarchy and not just the direct children.

So switch the selector to

```
#overlap-manager-root > div [data-value="CustomRange"]
```

and this should find your element.